# Pandas Dataframe get Top 1 results

Tags: pandas

How can I get the top 1 result row from pandas df?

here is the code so far:

```
string3 = df[(df['ruleid'] == '5700') & (df['timestamp'] > emp_1.timestamp) & (df['srcip'] == emp_1.srcip)].groupby('timestamp').head(1).values.flatten().tolist()


['1597829264', '11595380253', '51.26.761.11', '5700', '1595380199.679119', 'na', '1597829264', '11595380256', '51.26.761.11', '5700', '1595380199.679119', 'na', '1597829264', '11595380257', '51.26.761.11', '5700', '1595380199.679119', 'na', '1597829264', '11595380258', '51.26.761.11', '5700', '1595380199.679119', 'na']
```

Comment: Not sure if I am interpreting your question properly. You have ```head(1)``` which would grab the first row of the groupby object. You then convert it to a list. Are you wanting the first element in that list? If so ```strings3[0]```. A reproducible example that shows your expected results would be helpful.

Comment: df is created from csv file , if I use string[0] then I am getting the header of the csv

Comment: without seeing your csv file or having reproducible code, it is difficult.Looks like you read the file in, then subset based off values in ```ruleid```, ```timestamp```, and ```srcip```. Then you group this and convert it to a list. Why convert it to a list if you are wanting to call the entire first row of the group? Instead convert it to a dataframe. 
```string3 = pandas.DataFrame(df[(df['ruleid'] == '5700') & (df['timestamp'] > emp_1.timestamp) & (df['srcip'] == emp_1.srcip)].groupby('timestamp'))```
Then you can call string3[0] to get the first row of the grouped df.